# find hidden field value when link button is inside nested repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asplinkbutton, nested-controls

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptHotels" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHotels_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="hotel-box">
                            <div class="hotel-img">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnHotelCode" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("HotelCode")%>' />
                                <a class="preview" href='<%#Eval("ImageURL_Text") %>' title='<%#Eval("HotelName")%>' target="_blank">
                                    <img src='<%#Eval("ImageURL_Text") %>' alt='<%#Eval("HotelName")%>' height="75px"
                                        width="100px" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hotel_heeading_content">
                                <div class="hotel_heading">
                                    <h2>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHotelDetail" runat="server" OnClick="lnkHotelDetail_Click">                                      
                                            <%#Eval("HotelName")%>
                                            (
                                            <%#Eval("boardType")%>)
                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stars">
                                    <span class="stars">
                                        <%#Eval("StarRating")%></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hotel_text">
                                    <%#Eval("HotelAddress")%>,
                                    <%#Eval("Destination")%>
                                    ,<%#Eval("Country")%>
                                    <img src="images/ico_point2.png" alt="" id="mapicon" class="mapicon" />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLatitude" class="hdnLatitude" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("Latitude")%>' />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLongitude" class="hdnLongitude" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("Longitude")%>' />
                                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnInfoWindow" class="hdnInfoWindow" runat="server" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Literal ID="ltDes" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#">more info</a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="btn">

                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrice" runat="server"  Text=' <%#Eval("totalPrice")%>'  OnClick="lnkHotelDetail_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>


                            </div>
                            <div class="roominfo">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptRooms" runat="server">
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <div class="rooms">
                                            <div class="roominfoheader">
                                                <div class="roomheaderlbl">
                                                    Room Name</div>
                                                <div class="roomheaderlbl">
                                                    Total Room Rate</div>
                                                <div class="roomheaderlbl">
                                                    Book Now</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="rooms">
                                            <div class="roominforow">
                                                <div class="roominforowlbl">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRoomName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("roomCategory") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                                                <div class="roominforowlbl">
                                                    $
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("totalRoomRate") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                                                <div class="roominforowlbl">
                                                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBookNow" runat="server"  Text="Book Now" OnClick="lnkBookNow_Click"></asp:LinkButton></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I have above HTML for nested repeater .I am able to find the hidden field value which contain hotel Code by following method

```
protected void lnkHotelDetail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        var item = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        HiddenField hdnHotelCode = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnHotelCode");



    }
```

but the problem is now i have to find the hidden field value when a nested repeater item template link button is clicked .You can check that lnkBookNow is link button which is inside the `rptRooms` repeater.

```
protected void lnkBookNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        var item = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        HiddenField hdnHotelCode = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnHotelCode");


    }
```

I tried something like this but its not finding hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `lnkBookNow.NamingContainer` is `rptRooms`. This control obviously does not contain `hdnHotelCode`.

I think you should be able to do this with:

```
protected void lnkBookNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField hdnHotelCode = item.FindControl("hdnHotelCode") as HiddenField;
}
```

`btn.NamingContainer` is a `RepeaterItem` in `rptRooms`. The `NamingContainer` of that is the `Repeater` itself. Finally, the `NamingContainer` of `rptRooms` is the `RepeaterItem` of `rptHotels`, in which you want to find your `HiddenField`.

Note my use of the `as` keyword instead of an explicit cast - this will protect you from NullReferenceExceptions if `FindControl` returns null. Of course, you should explicitly check that `hdnHotelCode` isn't null before you try to access it.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem'.

Comment: Sorry, you may need another `.NamingContainer` there to pick up the `RepeaterItem` of `rptHotels` that `rptRooms` is in. I've updated my answer but can't test this at the minute - does this help?

Comment: well its works for me . thanks for this . do you have SDL Tridion   experienced in this ?

Comment: I have some experience integrating WebForms and Tridion -- not sure if this is considered off-topic but, if you're interested, we have an Area51 proposal for a Tridion StackExchange that we are trying to get to Beta: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion

Comment: i want to get some knowledge about SDL Tridion . is it possible for you to come in private chat on stackoverflow chat room  . If you have time ... thanks in advance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23450/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-ant-p)